# Change colors of individual graphic elements

Tags: graphics, color

I generated an array of circles/disks with an hexagonal packing. Now I want to give each circle/disk a color depending on the value of a second list.

```
Table 1: Coordinates of disks

1.) (x1/y1)
2.) (x2/y2)
3.) (x3/y3)
4.) (x4/y4)
...

Table 2: Colors
(Blue)
(Red)
(Green)
(Blue)
...


NumberRows = 10;
NumberColumns = 10;
Table1 = Table[{0.5 + i, 0.5 + (2*j*Sqrt[1 - 0.5^2])}, {i, 0, 
    NumberColumns - 1}, {j, 0, ((NumberRows - 2)/2)}];
Table2 = Table[{i, 0.5 + ((1 + 2*j)*Sqrt[1 - 0.5^2])}, {i, 0, 
    NumberColumns - 1}, {j, 0, ((NumberRows - 2)/2)}];

TableCombined = Join[Table1, Table2];
g3 = Flatten[TableCombined, 1];

points = Graphics[{Blue , Disk[#, 0.5] & /@ g3}];

Show[points, Frame -> True]
```

Comment: Try `disks = MapThread[{#1, Disk[#2, 0.5]}&, {listOfColors, g3}]; Graphics [disks, Frame -> True]`. Note that `listOfColors` should have the same length as `g3`.

Answer (score 1):

```
NumberRows = 10;
NumberColumns = 10;
Table1 = Table[{0.5 + i, 0.5 + (2*j*Sqrt[1 - 0.5^2])}, {i, 0, 
    NumberColumns - 1}, {j, 0, ((NumberRows - 2)/2)}];
Table2 = Table[{i, 0.5 + ((1 + 2*j)*Sqrt[1 - 0.5^2])}, {i, 0, 
    NumberColumns - 1}, {j, 0, ((NumberRows - 2)/2)}];

TableCombined = Join[Table1, Table2];
g3 = Flatten[TableCombined, 1];

g4 = Partition[Flatten@Riffle[g3, {Blue, Red, Green}, {1, -2, 2}], 3];

Show[Graphics[{First@#, Disk[Rest@#, 0.5]}] & /@ g4, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Or as @MarcoB suggests

```
listOfColors = Take[Flatten@Table[{Blue, Red, Green}, 35], Length@g3];

Graphics[MapThread[{#1, Disk[#2, 0.5]} &, {listOfColors, g3}], 
 Frame -> True]
```